# local variable 'i' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, recursion

Trying out some recursion based questions, came across this error.

'i' is the number of digits, which increments by 1. Where have I gone wrong?

## determine no. of digits by repeated div by 10

```
i = 0
def dig(n):

    if n < 10:
        i += 1
        return
    else:
        i += 1
        dig(n//10)

    print(i)


dig(123)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several issues. You define `i` outside your function, but only use it inside the function, that's causing the main issue. However, your function also has several logic errors.

It looks like you were going for:

```
def dig(n):
    if n < 10:
        return 1
    else:
        return 1 + dig(n//10)


print(dig(123))
```

But if you really want to use a global variable to 'count' the digits:

```
digits = 0


def dig(n):
    global digits
    digits += 1
    if n > 10:
        dig(n//10)
    return digits


print(dig(123))
```

Note that this has the problem that it only works once. If you call it again, you'll have to reset `digits` to `0` again first. It's not the best way to go and avoiding globals is generally a good idea.

If you need your function to include the call to `print()` instead of printing the result, you can modify the first solution like this:

```
def dig(n, c=1):
    if n < 10:
        print(c)
    else:
        dig(n//10, c+1)


dig(123)
```

But generally it tends to be more useful to have a function that returns a result, so it can be used in other places, instead of just printing a result once.

You indicated you need to store the count in a variable, which makes little sense if you were also asked to write a recursive function. Without recursion, it would look more like:

```
def dig(n):
    digits = 1
    while n > 10:
        n = n // 10
        digits += 1
    return digits


print(dig(123))
```

Comment: It was mentioned in the question to store the number of digits in a variable and increment it.

Comment: also i forgot to print i after calling ```dig()```, instead printing i for each loop :P

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct recursive function:

```
def dig(n, i = 0):
    #base case
    if n < 10:
        return i + 1
    #recursion
    return dig(n//10, i + 1)

print(dig(123))
#output: 3
```